# AcessibilityEvent in Flutter / Dart

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm 3 weeks looking for how to use the accessibility event with dart, has anyone got anything yet? I did not find anything in the documentation

Comment: This is not accurate

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility information can be provided via the [Semantics](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Semantics-class.html) widget. Most widgets in the Material and Cupertino libraries already provide relevant semantics, such as `MaterialButton`s identifying as a button and so on. The `Semantics` widget is only necessary if you create your own widgets out of primitive layouts or painters.

For example, say you wanted to make your own button and started with a `Text` widget and a gesture detector.

```
Widget build(_) {
  return Container(
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () { ... }
      child: Text('MY BUTTON'),
    )
  );
}
```

This will already contain some semantic information from the `Text` and `GestureDetector` widgets. While running the app, you can press `S` (capital "S") if TalkBack or VoiceOver is enabled to print the current semantic tree.

```
[   +6 ms] I/flutter ( 6511): SemanticsNode#0
[        ] I/flutter ( 6511):  │ Rect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 1080.0, 1794.0)
[        ] I/flutter ( 6511):  │
[        ] I/flutter ( 6511):  └─SemanticsNode#1
[        ] I/flutter ( 6511):      Rect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 79.0, 16.0) with transform
[        ] I/flutter ( 6511):        [2.625,0.0,0.0,436.3125; 0.0,2.625,0.0,876.0; 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0;
[        ] I/flutter ( 6511):        0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]
[        ] I/flutter ( 6511):      actions: tap
[        ] I/flutter ( 6511):      label: "MY BUTTON"
[        ] I/flutter ( 6511):      textDirection: ltr
```

In this case to specifically identify this as a button, you can wrap your widgets with a `Semantics` widget an provide `button: true` and `container: true`.

```
Widget build(_) {
  return Semantics(
    container: true,
    button: true,
    child: Container(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () { ... }
        child: Text('MY BUTTON'),
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I mean accessibility events, to automate my gizmo and in the future make a teamviewer on flutter

Send Clicks, etcs.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out. It introduces accessibility bridge in flutter than can be used to achieve what you want.

https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/view/AccessibilityBridge.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.